# Make a copy of a list and set an element in one line?

Tags: python

In my code, I make a copy of a list and then set one of the copy's elements to something other than the original. Can this operation be done **in one line**, preferably without using a filtered list comprehension? You might guess that the following code

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = list(a)[0] = 5
>>> b
```

produces `5`. Is there anyway `b` can instead point to `[5,2,3,4]`? I know this isn't a big space saver, and I'm really just wondering if it can be done cleanly, without explicitly creating the copy using a comprehension.

Comment: "Without explicitly creating a copy". Do you want that `a[0]` be `5`, too?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes that's vague...I meant a comprehension should not be used to create the copy and set the item. I'd like to use a function like `list()`.

Comment: Most questions along the line of "how do I do this and that without using this and that other" are maybe of academic interest, but of very low nutrition value. If there is an obvious solution, why not use it? -- In your case, you want to comprehend a list, but you don't want to use a list comprehension (one of python's fortes).

Comment: I agree with @Hyperboreous. My question is "why"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
b = [e if i != 0 else 5 for i, e in enumerate(a)]
```

Or:

```
b = [5] + a[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a helper function:

```
def with_replaced_element(l, i, x):
    l2 = l[:]
    l[i] = x
    return l2
```

Whether the helper function is worth it depends on how many times you would be using it. If this is something your code needs to do a lot of, and it would make your code cleaner to have an expression instead of multiple statements, then go for it.